# Не работает скроллбар tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

У меня есть есть такая иерархия: окно, в нём фрейм, в этом фрейме так же фрейм и в нём холст. В холсте с помощью кнопки создаются элементы и рядом с холстом в одном и том же фрейме есть скроллбар который по идее должен прокручивать холст по вертикали но почему то он этого не делает.

```
root = tk.Tk()
root.resizable(False, False)
root.title('Canvas')
root.attributes("-fullscreen", True)

c = tk.Canvas(root, bg='#F0F0F0')
c.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')

frame = tk.Frame(root, bg='#F7F7F7') # головной фрейм
frame.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='nsew')

def close():
    root.destroy()

exit = tk.Button(frame, text='Close', relief="flat")
exit.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='s', padx=10, pady=10, columnspan=2)
exit.config(command=close, width=10)

dot_controls = tk.Frame(frame, bg='#F0F0F0',  height=700) # подфрейм
dot_controls.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nwe', padx=40, pady=40, rowspan=2)
dot_controls.config(height=700, width=360)
dot_controls.grid_propagate(0)

dot_list = tk.Canvas(dot_controls, bg='#F0F0F0',  height=700, highlightthickness=0) # холст в подфрейме
dot_list.grid(row=0, column=0, rowspan=2, sticky='nwe')
dot_list_scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(dot_controls, orient='vertical', command=dot_list.yview) # скроллбар
dot_list_scrollbar.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky='ns', rowspan=10)
dot_list.configure(yscrollcommand=dot_list_scrollbar.set)
dot_list.grid_propagate(0)

row_num = 0

dots_center = []

num = tk.Label(dot_list, text='№', fg='#8F8F8F')
num.grid(row=row_num, column=0)

value_head = tk.Label(dot_list, text='Name', fg='#8F8F8F')
value_head.grid(row=row_num, column=1)

X = tk.Label(dot_list, text='X', fg='#8F8F8F')
X.grid(row=row_num, column=2)

Y = tk.Label(dot_list, text='Y', fg='#8F8F8F')
Y.grid(row=row_num, column=3)

start_row = tk.Label(dot_list, text=row_num+1, fg='#8F8F8F')
start_row.grid(row=row_num+1, column=0, sticky='n')


def callback(input): # фильтр ввода
    if input.find('e') != -1:
        return False
    try:
        print(input+'1')
        input = float(input+'1')
        return True
    except:
        print('no')
        return False

reg=root.register(callback)

# создание оглавнения для строчек
value = tk.Entry(dot_list)
value.grid(row=row_num+1, column=1, sticky='n')
value.insert(0,'None')

posX = tk.Entry(dot_list)
posX.grid(row=row_num+1, column=2, sticky='n')
posX.insert(0,'0')
posX.config(validate="key", validatecommand=(reg, '%P'))

posY = tk.Entry(dot_list)
posY.grid(row=row_num+1, column=3, sticky='n')
posY.insert(0,'0')
posY.config(validate="key", validatecommand=(reg, '%P'))

row_num = 1

def def_add(): # создание строчек
    global start_row
    global row_num
    global value
    global posX
    global posY


    row_num = row_num + 1

    start_row = tk.Label(dot_list, text=row_num, fg='#8F8F8F')
    start_row.grid(row=row_num, column=0, sticky='n')

    value = tk.Entry(dot_list)
    value.grid(row=row_num, column=1, sticky='n')
    value.insert(0, 'None')

    posX = tk.Entry(dot_list)
    posX.grid(row=row_num, column=2, sticky='n')
    posX.insert(0, '0')
    posX.config(validate="key", validatecommand=(reg, '%P'))

    posY = tk.Entry(dot_list)
    posY.grid(row=row_num, column=3, sticky='n')
    posY.insert(0, '0')
    posY.config(validate="key", validatecommand=(reg, '%P'))

    root.update()
```

Вот что получается:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы `canvas` скроллировался, не достаточно в него напихать виджетов просто так. Т.к. в этом случае `bbox` его содержимого так и останется пустым (и `scrollbar`, соответственно, будет считать, что скроллировать нечего). Надо в `canvas` создать `window`, и уже в него помещать все остальные виджеты. А также перехватить событие изменения этого окна, чтобы пересчитать скроллируемый регион.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

def def_add(): # создание строчек
    global start_row
    global row_num
    global value
    global posX
    global posY


    row_num += 1

    start_row = tk.Label(dot_list, text=row_num, fg='#8F8F8F')
    start_row.grid(row=row_num, column=0, sticky='n')

    value = tk.Entry(dot_list)
    value.grid(row=row_num, column=1, sticky='n')
    value.insert(0, 'None')

    posX = tk.Entry(dot_list)
    posX.grid(row=row_num, column=2, sticky='n')
    posX.insert(0, '0')
    posX.config(validate="key", validatecommand=(reg, '%P'))

    posY = tk.Entry(dot_list)
    posY.grid(row=row_num, column=3, sticky='n')
    posY.insert(0, '0')
    posY.config(validate="key", validatecommand=(reg, '%P'))

def close():
    root.destroy()

def update_scrollregion(event):
    dot_canvas.configure(scrollregion=dot_canvas.bbox("all"))

def callback(input): # фильтр ввода
    if input.find('e') != -1:
        return False
    try:
        print(input+'1')
        input = float(input+'1')
        return True
    except:
        print('no')
        return False


root = tk.Tk()
#root.resizable(False, False)
root.title('Canvas')
#root.attributes("-fullscreen", True)
root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

reg = root.register(callback)

c = tk.Canvas(root, bg='#F0F0F0')
c.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')

frame = tk.Frame(root, bg='#F7F7F7') # головной фрейм
frame.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='nsew')
frame.rowconfigure(0, weight=1) 

dot_controls = tk.Frame(frame, bg='#F0F0F0') # подфрейм 
dot_controls.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nswe', padx=40, pady=40, columnspan=2)
dot_controls.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
dot_controls.columnconfigure(0, weight=1) 

add = tk.Button(frame, text='Add', relief="flat")
add.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='s', padx=10, pady=10)
add.config(command=def_add, width=10)

exit = tk.Button(frame, text='Close', relief="flat")
exit.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='s', padx=10, pady=10)
exit.config(command=close, width=10)

dot_canvas = tk.Canvas(dot_controls, bg='#F0F0F0', highlightthickness=0) # холст в подфрейме
dot_canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

canvas_frame = tk.Frame(dot_canvas, bg="#EBEBEB")
dot_canvas.create_window(0, 0, window=canvas_frame, anchor='nw')

scroll = ttk.Scrollbar(dot_controls, orient='vertical', command=dot_canvas.yview) # скроллбар
dot_canvas.config(yscrollcommand=scroll.set)
scroll.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="ns")

canvas_frame.bind("<Configure>", update_scrollregion)

# заголовок
row_num = 0
dot_list = canvas_frame

num = tk.Label(dot_list, text='№', fg='#8F8F8F')
num.grid(row=row_num, column=0)

value_head = tk.Label(dot_list, text='Name', fg='#8F8F8F')
value_head.grid(row=row_num, column=1)

X = tk.Label(dot_list, text='X', fg='#8F8F8F')
X.grid(row=row_num, column=2)

Y = tk.Label(dot_list, text='Y', fg='#8F8F8F')
Y.grid(row=row_num, column=3)

for _ in range(10):
    def_add()

root.mainloop()
```

[image: скриншот]